# How do I create partitioned table from result set in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I just created partitioned table from result set to make sure I understood properly.
From hacker news only three columns are taken namely time_ts, title and score. 
from 2013-2015, 1015 partitions are created.
from 2007-2015, 3158 partitions.(exceeds the limit)

```
Query-1
Creating partitioned table based on date column.(2013-2015)
create table mydataset.y2013_y2015(title_date date, title string, score int64) partition by title_date as 
select extract(date from time_ts)extracted_date,title,score from `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`  where extract(date from time_ts) between '2013-01-01' and '2015-12-31'

Query-2
Creating partitioned table based on timestamp column.(2013-2015)
create table mydataset.y2013_y2015_ts(title_ts timestamp, title string, score int64) partition by date(title_ts) as 
select time_ts,title,score from `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`  where extract(date from time_ts) between '2013-01-01' and '2015-12-31'

Query-3 
Creating partitioned table based on timestamp column.(2007-2015)
create table mydataset.y2007_y2015(ts timestamp, title string, score int64) partition by date(ts) as 
select time_ts,title,score from `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`  where extract(date from time_ts) between '2007-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
Error: Too many partitions produced by query, allowed 2000, query produces at least 3158 partitions
```

Query-1 and Query-2 creates partitioned table from result set.

To check - how many partitions are created.

```
select COUNT(*)No_of_partitions from [mydataset.y2013_y2015$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__] 
select COUNT(*)No_of_partitions from  [mydataset.y2013_y2015_ts$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes .You are correct.
You can also use this code (in standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
select count(distinct _PARTITIONDATE) from `mydataset.y2013_y2015`
```